# How do i cancel a specific timer?

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, cancellation, periodic-task

If i am running 3 different timer for 3 different function how do i cancel a specific one.

Example

```
const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 60);
        new Timer.periodic(
            oneSec,
            (Timer t) async =>
                await appLoggerRepository.putAppLogOnServer(jobName));

const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 60);
        new Timer.periodic(
            oneSec,
            (Timer t) async =>
                await appLoggerRepository.uploadOrder(jobName));

const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 60);
        new Timer.periodic(
            oneSec,
            (Timer t) async =>
                await appLoggerRepository.checkdevice(jobName));

~~
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a timer variable

```dart
Timer logTimer = Timer.periodic( //no need for the new keyword
            oneSec,
            (Timer t) async =>
                await appLoggerRepository.putAppLogOnServer(jobName));

//to cancel call cancel()
logTimer.cancel();
```